# Selecting cyrillic text from the database using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, cyrillic

I have problems with selecting cyrillic text from the database. I get some undefined characters instead of letters. I've been searching the internet for the whole day but nothing.

Connection function:

```
protected function pdo_connect(){
    $instance = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.self::SERVER_DB_DATABASE.';host='.self::SERVER_DB_HOST.';charset=utf8', self::SERVER_DB_USER, self::SERVER_DB_PASS);
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
    return $instance;
}
```

And selecting the text from the database:

```
$temp=array();
$stmt=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$result=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
for($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++){ 
    $temp[$result[$i]['text_index']]['en']=$result[$i]['en'];
    $temp[$result[$i]['text_index']]['sr_lat']=$result[$i]['sr_lat'];
    $temp[$result[$i]['text_index']]['sr_cyr']=$result[$i]['sr_cyr'];
}
return $temp;
```

And when I select the data from the database I get something like this:
[image]
As you can see, the cyrillic text isn't displayed properly but it's properly displayed in the database:
[image]

And to mention that I have headers set:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

So what is the problem here?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Mihai Still nothing. I changed character set on all tables and columns, changed connection method and charset in header but I still get undefined symbols.

Comment: Do you have this `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your `<head>` tag?

Comment: @Mihai Yes, I tried with and without that (in combination with php header(charset)) but again nothing.

Comment: Any change if you remove  charset=utf8' from PDO?

Comment: @Mihai Oh... I've just seen what I had done. I've been doing var_dump() for the whole time on the config.php page instead on the index.php so the charset was always under the output. I added some things and it's fine now. However, thank you very much for the link with utf8mb4 charset, I think it'll help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try correct your connection code to:

```
protected function pdo_connect(){
    $instance = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.self::SERVER_DB_DATABASE.';host='.self::SERVER_DB_HOST.';charset=utf8', self::SERVER_DB_USER, self::SERVER_DB_PASS);
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8; SET CHARACTER SET utf8; SET SESSION collation_connection = utf8_general_ci;');
    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: As I've already said in comments, I solved my problem by thanks anyway.